# Shifted argument in PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my research, I have come across the following differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d f(x,t)}{dt} = \left[ f(x,t) - 1 \right] f(x+\alpha,t)
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is some constant. I have never seen such an equation before. Any suggestions how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so-called mixed functional differential equation. There is a quite detailed account of the theory of such equations in [Mixed functional differential equations](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-005-0345-2?LI=true).

Answer (score 0):

The transform
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(x,t,\rho) = \int d\alpha~~  f(x+\alpha,t) e^{-\alpha x}
\end{equation}
turns the equation into an ordinary differential equation for $\Lambda$.